# Get audio in backend of each voice input Google Assistant (Dialogflow Google)

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant

Please, could you help me solve this query?

Developed an agent in Dialogflow for users to interact by their voice. She integrated it into Google Assistant.

**How can I get the audio of each input that the user tells me?**

That is, if the user, through Google Assistant (on the mobile or speaker) indicates this input with a voice: "My name is Juan Pérez", I would like to be able to retrieve the audio (not the text, but the audio file with your voice) from backend.

Is this possible?

thank you

All the best

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The platform through Actions on Google does not provide a way to access the audio uttered by the user.